# Считать ли перечислением без двоеточия?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть фраза из договора составленная не очень корректно, но из песни слов не выкинешь. Каждый трактует её в свою пользу.

"На дату возникновения у Покупателя права собственности на земельный участок уплатить полностью все коммунальные платежи, налоги и иные расходы, которые причитаются с собственника земельного участка, за строительство общей дороги, проведение водопровода, установки электрических столбов и выделения электромощностей."

Вопрос: Если прочитать по нормам русского языка, то под словом ИНЫЕ подразумевается только то, что перечислено далее, т.е. "*за строительство общей дороги, проведение водопровода, установки электрических столбов и выделения электромощностей*" или **иные расходы** - это не только то, что перечислено?

Если бы стояло двоеточие, то все было бы понятно, а без него сложности.

**Обновление**

Большое спасибо всем за ответы.
Конечно фраза вырвана из контекста.
Это из списка обязанностей продавца.
До фразы стоит конструкция которую нужно понимать как "Продавец обязан".

Правильно ли я понял из ваших объяснений, что эта фраза все же ограничила список платежей только тем, что перечислено? Например, платеж за установку забора сюда под слово "иные" уже не подведешь?

Comment: Если вы не можете договориться между собой, вас поможет разве что лингвоэкпертиза и суд. Здесь такого не делают. Все что тут сказано юрилической силы не имеет - и может быть просто не принято во внимание вашим оппонентом

Comment: Ключевые слова для собственника — «уплатить полностью».

Comment: @shampar  *Ключевые слова для собственника — «уплатить полностью»* - а не подскажете, давно это понятие "ключевые слова" стало основанием для трактовки положений договора?

Comment: *Правильно ли я понял из ваших объяснений, что эта фраза все же ограничила список платежей* -  я совсем так не думаю. Подробности - в моем ответе.

Comment: А кстати, есть где-нибудь список платежей попадающих под понятие "причитающихся с собственника земельного участка"? Все же одет очень просто решаться. Если "за строительство общей дороги, проведение водопровода, установки электрических столбов и выделения электромощностей" - это те взносы, которые "не причитаются", то их появление в этом списке отдельной строкой не удивительно. И если не секрет, о каком все-таки спорном платеже идет речь? И что вообще за ситуация, с кого требуют покрытия?

Comment: Есть отдельный платеж за строительство забора. Продавец считает, что он не был включен в этот список, а покупатель, что включен в понятие "иные".

Comment: ... иные расходы, причитающиеся с собственника(,) за первое, второе, третье и четвёртое. Уточняющее (что такое "иные") перечисление здесь завершённое (применён союз "и") - как можно отсюда вывести что-то ещё? Даже затесавшуюся лишнюю запятую нельзя трактовать как разделитель, завершающий предыдущее суждение (была бы точка, тогда "иные" можно было бы трактовать произвольно), поскольку предлог "за" и следующий за ним ограничительный список грамматически согласованы только с оборотом "причитающиеся с собственника".

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых фраза неполная. Нет ни глагола-сказуемого, ни даже подлежащего. Как тут можно что-то понять, не знаю. Что за конструкция вообще? Так нигде нет спереди "покупатель обязан" или "продавец" или "собственник"?

Во-вторых, вы совершенно верно сказали, что документ составлен неграмотно, "и иные" должно последнем в списке или отделяться от последующей части с помощью чем-то наподобие "а так же" или "в том числе". А так остается только гадать, то ли дальше следуют "расходы" (почему расходы-то, а не платежи?!), которые не попадают почему-то "в иные" (но обязательные к уплате), то ли запятая там лишняя ("иные расходы за строительство общей дороги" - чем не вариант?) то ли пропущено двоеточие.

В любом случае вам стоит не уповать на расшифровку этого текста в том виде, как он составлен, а показать, что тот или иной платеж подпадает или не подпадает под исчерпывающий список платежей, обязательство по которым возникает на момент приобретения права собственности. Это более перспективный путь решения подобных споров в досудебном порядке.

Короче, если хотя бы одна сторона, тем более обе сильно упрется, дело может разрешить только суд. По идее он будет руководствоваться не столько тестом данного договора, сколько общими положениями (жилищным или гражданским кодексом, уставом кооператива - или что там у вас), где в явном виде прописано, кто, когда, за что и сколько должен платить.

(+)

Да, если действительно дойдет до экспертизы (с юристом посоветуйтесь!), её делают, например, вот тут:

http://www.rusexpert.ru/

Но дело это не быстрое и не дешевое.

UPD

> Правильно ли я понял из ваших объяснений, что эта фраза все же
>   ограничила список платежей только тем, что перечислено? Например,
>   платеж за установку забора сюда под слово "иные" уже не подведешь?

Нет и еще раз нет. Любая трактовка тут ошибочна, кроме экспертной. Но на мой взгляд о каком-то ограничении надо думать в последнюю очередь. Слово "иные" вообще не нужно перед исчерпывающим списком.

> На словах покупатель получил от продавца заверения, что ВСЕ платежи
>   включены, а как следует теперь из документа не все, но т.к. документ
>   составлен неграмотно можно на этом сыграть.

Это детали, кто там, куда вписал. Вы суть спора-то дайте. 
Это просто умозрительное предположение, что кто-то может оспорить? Или уже есть конкретный повод?

Вы "доиграетесь" до того, что сделку признают недействительной (даже ничтожной) на том основании, что смысл её не ясен сторонам на момент заключения. (Статья 178 ГК РФ - и аналогичные).

Мой прогноз все тот же. И "иные причитающиеся" платежи - это ***все причитающиеся***, независимо от перечисления. Если иное не указано явно. А иначе, зачем вообще там слово иные? Ну и еще такой момент, это правда совсем не филология, но весьма актуально. Есть общий базовый принцип (совсем не только российский), что отчуждаемое по сделке имущество, должна быть свободна от всякого обременения - назвал так, чтобы в юридические дебри на залезать - т.е. всяких обязательств продавца перед кем-либо, долги и причине обязательства на покупателя не переходят, если иное не указано в договоре. Так что тут ловить - да еще не имея конкретного события - просто не знаю.

Но, повторяю, это мой взгляд. Я не юрист. И в общем-то даже не лингвист.)))

Comment: Часть фразы ", за строительство общей дороги, проведение водопровода, установки электрических столбов и выделения электромощностей" была дописана в последний момент продавцом который хотел вроде как уточнить, а покупатель по неграмотности принял такие уточнения. На словах покупатель получил от продавца заверения, что ВСЕ платежи включены, а как следует теперь из документа не все, но т.к. документ составлен неграмотно можно на этом сыграть.

Comment: Ответил в тексте.

Answer (score 0):

В этой фразе есть орфографические ошибки ("установку" и "выделение" должны быть в винительном падеже; после слова "участка" не должно быть запятой). Однако, что касается слова "иные", его можно трактовать только как "иные **виды платежей**" (не только уже названные **коммунальные** платежи с **налогами**, а возможно, и "*штрафы*", "*отчисления*" и пр. если они предусмотрены). Относиться же эти "иные" виды платежей (= *иные расходы*) могут здесь **только к тому, что перечислено**; на это никак не влияет отсутствие двоеточия. За пределы перечисленных возможных направлений расходов могло бы вывести указание "и тому подобное" в самом конце или наличие слов "например", "таких как", "в частности" перед "за строительство...".

Comment: *Относиться же эти "иные" виды платежей (= иные расходы) могут здесь только к тому, что перечислено; на это никак не влияет отсутствие двоеточия* - боже, откуда такая уверенность?

Comment: Вопрос не стоял о юридической значимости сказанного (юристы могут и за его пределами найти причитающееся). Если бы эта фраза заканчивалась словом "участка", можно было бы трактовать "причитающееся" в предельно широком смысле, но автор добавил к "иным" видам расходов ограничение на статьи расходов,

Comment: *Вопрос не стоял о юридической значимости сказанного* - мой вопрос стоял о ***Вашей*** уверенности, которую я не могу понять ни в какой плоскости.  В юридической - безусловно, но если бы только в ней. Удивляет сам подход, как можно говорить о правильном понимании неправильно составленной фразы, основываясь исключительно на догадках. А если пишущий по-другому рассуждал, не так как Вы?  Впрочем, спасибо. Не смею настаивать.